# Null propagation + null coalescing operator not working as expected when dealing with InnerException

Tags: c#, .net, c#-6.0

For a simple console application that I am developing I want to implement a very basic exception handling (just printing the exception message and terminating the program). The logic that I want to implement is: if the exception has an inner exception, print the inner's message; otherwise print the own exceptions's message.

I tried to implement it using the new C# 6 null propagation operator as follows:

```
try
{
    //Test case 1:
    throw new Exception("Foo", new Exception("Bar"));

    //Test case 2:
    throw new Exception("Foo");
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("--- Error: " + 
        ex.InnerException?.Message ?? ex.Message);
}
```

The problem is that while test case 1 works as expected (prints `--- Error: Bar`), test case 2 just prints `--- Error:` instead of the expected `--- Error: Foo`.

I think that I am somehow misunderstanding how the null propagation operator works (possible how it works together with the null coalescing operator). What am I missing?

*Note:* please don't tell me how to implement the same behavior using C# 5 (thank you but I know already); I am specifically interested in how the null propagation operator works.

Comment: Never ever do this, use the exception object's ToString() method.  It never gets it wrong and that stack trace is pretty important.

Comment: @PeterDuniho `ex.InnerException?.Message` uses the `?.` operator.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Please look closely. I am using both.

Comment: A close vote for "off-topic"? Seriously???

Comment: Sorry...I did look closely, but apparently not closely enough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are doing now is this:

```
("--- Error: " + ex.InnerException?.Message) ?? ex.Message
```

The null-coalescing operator goes over the first part, not over your exception part. Since that yields `"--- Error: " + null`, it is not null and proceeds.

Use this:

```
"--- Error: " + (ex.InnerException?.Message ?? ex.Message)
```

(Note it is better to do a `.ToString()` on the exception rather than getting its message. Now you lose the call stack, etc.)

Comment: Thank you! Agree about the `.ToString()`, but it is a very simple throwaway application and I'm really interested in just the message in this case.